# Calculate Y1 of second line which is half the size of first line

Tags: javascript, math

I have a line with this values (x1, y1, x2, y2):

```
20, 100, 120, 120
```

How I can get the second lines Y1 so that is on the same height of the first lines Y1 (the second line is half the size or different than line 1)?

```
70, 100, 120, 120
```

The second line looks with the values above so:

[image]
Also the output should look like this picture:

[image]

Comment: Your question and clear and what have you tried so far?

Comment: By direct proof, first_y1 == second_y1 => 100 == 100 => True. :D (That's a way of saying that you've already solved what you asked for.) Perhaps you meant _parallel_? That line 1 is parallel to line 2?

Comment: Yes, I meant so that line 2(y1) is parallel to line 1(y1).

Comment: @MaheerAli I try atan2 for the second line without success. **var  a = Math.atan2(120-100, 120-70);** 70, 100*a, 120, 120

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What do these numbers mean? What does same height and half the size mean?

Comment: @NicoSchertler The numbers are x1, y1, x2, y2. With "same height" I mean so that the Y1 of the second line should be where the Y1 of the first line is. With "half the size" I mean that the second line is half the size of first line. I edit the question please look at the new pictures.

Comment: What parts of the second line do you want to keep?

Comment: All values except Y1. Because Y1 of the second line should be on the same line where line 1 is.

Comment: So let me try to get this straight. You have a line L1 and a line L2. You want to modify L2.y1, such that L2.y1=L1.y2, the width of L2 is half the width of L1, and the height of L2 is half the height of L1. This does not work in general. You have one degree of freedom and three constraints.

Comment: L2.Y1 should be not direct on L1.Y1, but on the same line like showed in the second picture. Will this work?

Comment: Still over-constrained. You can modify it such that it is on the line. But then, you cannot guarantee the length constraint (50% of L1).

Comment: Ok, what will the math for this? Is it also possible to make it so that it is exactly on the line and make the length a few smaller or lager? I try so far this: **var n = x1+((x2-x1)/2);** _y1 = y1+(y2-y1)/n+((y2-y1)/2);_

Comment: So just `l2.x2 = (l1.x1 + l1.x2) / 2` and `l2.y2 = (l1.y1 + l1.y2) / 2`?

Comment: Okay, that's easier :) But how do you know what L2.Y1 is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula Approach:

```js
console.log(getCoordinates(20,10,120,50,1/4));
console.log(getCoordinates(60,10,160,50,1/2));
console.log(getCoordinates(100,10,200,50,3/4));

//factor = 1/2 if 50%
//factor = 3/4 if 75% and so on
function getCoordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2, factor){
let x3 = 0,
    y3 = 0;

x3 = (x2-x1)*factor+x1;
y3 = (y2-y1)*factor+y1;

return {x3:x3, y3:y3}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="20" y1="10" x2="120" y2="50" stroke="red" />
<line x1="45" y1="20" x2="120" y2="50" stroke="green" />

<line x1="60" y1="10" x2="160" y2="50" stroke="blue" />
<line x1="110" y1="30" x2="160" y2="50" stroke="orange" />

<line x1="100" y1="10" x2="200" y2="50" stroke="black" />
<line x1="175" y1="40" x2="200" y2="50" stroke="yellow" />


<line x1="20" y1="100" x2="120" y2="120" stroke="red" />
<line x1="45" y1="105" x2="120" y2="120" stroke="green" />

<line x1="60" y1="100" x2="160" y2="120" stroke="blue" />
<line x1="110" y1="110" x2="160" y2="120" stroke="orange" />

<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="200" y2="120" stroke="black" />
<line x1="175" y1="115" x2="200" y2="120" stroke="yellow" />

</svg>
```

Second Approach:

You can consider using gradient to get an output that looks like what you want.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<line x1="15" y1="5" x2="120" y2="120" stroke="url(#myGradient25)" />

<line x1="25" y1="5" x2="130" y2="120" stroke="url(#myGradient75)" />

<line x1="35" y1="5" x2="140" y2="120" stroke="url(#myGradient50)" />

 
  
  <!-- Stroke a circle with a gradient -->
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient25">
      <stop offset="25%"   stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <!-- Stroke a circle with a gradient -->
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient75">
      <stop offset="75%"   stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
   <!-- Stroke a circle with a gradient -->
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient50">
      <stop offset="50%"   stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Let me know if you require two line super imposed on each other and explain the rationale ?

Comment: I need the Math for this. Because the second line can be half the size or different than the first line.

Comment: You can set the offset - in percentage accordingly to the size you require - say you need 3/4 you can set offset to 25% and 75% respectively ?

Comment: Yes, but is there not a mathematic formula to calculate it?

Comment: In the example above the line is half the size, so I need to know the Y1 for the second line so it is on the same height like in the second picture. The second line can also be 3/4 length or any value. Therefore I search for a way to calculate this.

Comment: @JCss we could definitely derive the formula - but do you really require one line to super impose over another ? because the point needs to be approximated on the line in order to get over the limitations of discrete mathematics - worth spending time - only if that is very essentially needed

Comment: @JCss could you please refresh the page - I have updated the answer with few other combinations - you can check the code

Comment: I have more lines which has different length and want to match the Y1 to the first line.

Comment: when you have say 5 lines which needs to be super imposed on one line - visually only one line will be visible with different gradient - you don't have to actually super impose the lines but simply calculate the difference and set the gradient. If you go on a quest for the mathematical formula you will succeed in deriving but it will be giving you a point like (22.54323423425.., 33.123123124325436..) which can't be painted precisely on screen and hence the lines might not very precisely super impose on one another

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190207/discussion-between-jcss-and-takrishna).

Comment: Well, when I try this it will work with decimal numbers: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G270SF33UMJH

Comment: Thank you very much! The formula helps me further and the gradient idea is also a good approach :)